# read all contents of a txt file and parse it to JSON format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In `demo.txt` file:

```
'{
  "cars": {
    "Nissan": [
      {"model":"Sentra", "doors":4},
      {"model":"Maxima", "doors":4}
    ]
  }
}'
```

Expected result:

```
{
  "cars" => {
    "Nissan" => [
      {
        "model"=>"Sentra", 
        "doors"=>4
      },
      {
        "model" => "Maxima",
        "doors"=>4
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to read whole content of the file and parse it to JSON format like `JSON.parse(file_contents)`.Help me out.

I have tried like:

```
file_contents = File.readlines 'demo.txt'  
arr = []
file_contents.each do |d|
  puts arr << d.gsub("\n","")
end
puts arr # ["'{", "\"cars\": {", "\"Nissan\": [", "{\"model\":\"Sentra\", \"doors\":4},", "{\"model\":\"Maxima\", \"doors\":4}", "]", "}", "}'"]

puts arr * '' #"'{\"cars\": {\"Nissan\": [{\"model\":\"Sentra\", \"doors\":4},{\"model\":\"Maxima\", \"doors\":4}]}}'"
```

Comment: Have you tried any code logic? please post it here.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file contains this string.

```
str =
"'{
   \"cars\": {
     \"Nissan\": [
       {\"model\":\"Sentra\", \"doors\":4},
       {\"model\":\"Maxima\", \"doors\":4}
     ]
   }
  }'"
  #=> "'{\n   \"cars\": {\n     \"Nissan\": [\n       {\"model\":\"Sentra\", \"doors\":4},\n       {\"model\":\"Maxima\", \"doors\":4}\n     ]\n   }\n  }'"
```

Let's create the file.

```
FName = 'temp'

File.write(FName, str)
  #=> 152
```

We can JSON-parse the file after removing the single quotes.

```
require 'json'

JSON.parse(File.read(FName)[1..-2])
  #=> {"cars"=>{"Nissan"=>[{"model"=>"Sentra", "doors"=>4},
  #                        {"model"=>"Maxima", "doors"=>4}]}}
```

If the last line of the file ends with a newline, the file would be

```
str1 = str + "\n"
  #=> "'{\n   \"cars\": {\n     \"Nissan\": [\n       {\"model\":\"Sentra\", \"doors\":4},\n       {\"model\":\"Maxima\", \"doors\":4}\n     ]\n   }\n  }'\n" 
File.write(FName, str1)
  #=> 153
```

In this case we need to `chomp` before `[1..-2]`.

```
JSON.parse(File.read(FName).chomp[1..-2])
  #=> {"cars"=>{"Nissan"=>[{"model"=>"Sentra", "doors"=>4}, {"model"=>"Maxima", "doors"=>4}]}}
```

We could have instead written

```
JSON.parse(File.read(FName)[1..-3])
```

but the former has the advantage that it works regardless of whether the file ends with a newline.

Answer (score 3):

If you can strip out the leading and trailing `'` with gsub or something else, it's as simple as

```
require 'JSON'
JSON.parse(File.open('demo.txt').read.chop!.reverse.chop!.reverse)
```

Comment: Can you plz give complete solution.Thanks.

Comment: Updated with quick hack to fix this, would suggest solving this problem in your saved input format instead of doing this on every parse...